# Newbie: How to Add Multiple Listtile in Flutter

Tags: api, flutter, listview, dart

I have this code that I can't get to work properly. I need to get API object that consist of name, address, region, phone, and province but I don't know how to add more String in ListTile. My code was:

HOSPITAL CLASS

```
String name;
String address;
String region;
String phone;
String province;

factory HospitalList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HospitalList(
    name: json["name"],
    address: json["address"],
    region: json["region"],
    phone: json["phone"],
    province: json["province"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "name": name,
    "address": address,
    "region": region,
    "phone": phone,
    "province": province,
};
```

}

LISTRS CLASS

```
ListView _rsListView(data) {
return ListView.builder(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
    itemCount: data.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      // return data[index];
      return _tile(
          data[index].name, data[index].address, Icons.medical_services);
    }
    );

ListTile _tile( String title, String subtitle, IconData icon) => 
ListTile(
    title: Text(title,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        fontSize: 20,
      )
    ),
    subtitle: Text(subtitle,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
        fontSize: 15
      ),
    ),
    leading: Icon(icon, color: Colors.black),
  );
```

Is there a simple solution to added more String index in ListStyle?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for `ListTile`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html), it is fixed-height and does not support more than three lines of text. If you check it, they provide a sample for creating your own that [*can* support more than three lines.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html#material.ListTile.5)

However, I found that if you add a breakline (`\n`) in your subtitle text, it actually works how you’d expect it to.

`$varName` allows for inline variables in Strings. Because you’re referring to a variable within a variable, you’ll wrap that in curly brackets `${var.name}`, then you add a new line with `\n`. So your subtitle should look a little like this:

```dart
"${data[index].address}\n${data[index].region}\n${data[index].phone}\n${data[index].province}"
```